Substituting ln(1) for 0 to solve different classes of problems normally not possible due to division by zero
I saw a video on YouTube about finding an answer to equations like:
$1^x = 5$
Which normally would not be possible as you stumble upon a division by 0:

$\ln(1^x) = \ln(5)$
$x\ln(1) = \ln(5)$
$x = \frac{\ln(5)}{\ln(1)}$
$x = \frac{\ln(5)}{0}$

The way to find a solution goes like this:
$k\in\mathbb{Z}, k \not=0$

$(e^{i2k\pi})^x = 5$ (substituting 1 using Euler's formula)
$e^{i2k\pi \cdot x} = 5$ (applying a power rule bringing down the $x$)
$\ln(e^{i2k\pi \cdot x}) = \ln(5)$
$i2k\pi \cdot x \cdot \ln(e) = \ln(5)$ (applying a logarithm law to bring out the exponent)
$\Large x = \frac{\ln(5)}{i2k\pi}$
$\Large x = -\frac{i \cdot \ln(5)}{2k\pi}$

This got me thinking about why this shouldn't work for limits
Take this as an example:
$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^2}{x-2}$
Using a similar idea of thought I can substitute in our value of x, namely 2:
$k\in\mathbb{Z}, k \not=0$

$\Large\frac{2^2}{2-2}$
$\Large\frac{4}{0}$
$\Large\frac{4}{\ln(1)}$
$\Large\frac{4}{\ln(e^{i2k\pi})}$
$\Large\frac{4}{i2k\pi \cdot \ln(e)}$
$\Large -\frac{2i}{k\pi}$

If the first is seen as a valid answer to the equation $1^x = 5$ the second must also be seen as a valid answer as they, when reduced, are practically identical. To me, both seem invalid as they circumvent a division by zero which is there. Are they valid and if so I guess I am wondering why it's okay to ignore a division by zero sometimes and sometimes not?

The limit is taken through the reals only.  It matters.  For instance, $\lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right)=0$ as a real limit, but it diverges as a complex limit.

@lulu what's a complex limit? Is it something like $\lim_{x→i} f(x)$?

@Gwen  Use the norm in the complex plane.  Then, writing $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)=L$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta$ such that $0<|z-z_0|<\delta\implies |f(z)-L|<\epsilon$.  Same definition as for reals, but now all the terms can take complex values.  For the example I gave, if you try to approach $0$ along the imaginary axis, the function blows up.  That singularity isn't visible along the real line.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. If you want to exploit a function being multi-branched you need problem statements involving branches, e.g. "find all $z\in\Bbb C$ for which some branch of $\ln$ satisfies $e^{z\ln1}=5$" or "find how $\frac{z^2}{\ln e^{z-2}}$ behaves on each branch of $\ln$ as $z\to2$ along a path compatible with that branch".

@J.G. Hello, and thank you! I see, interesting. It flies a bit over my head but in what sort of class should I expect to first stumble on the concept of branches? I have heard about it in conjunction with the Lambert W function but not logarithms.

It'll come up in any decent course on contour integration. For now though, all that matters is a branch choice picks which $k$ appears in $\ln1=i2k\pi$.
